# Canvas as Image in Button WPF

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button, canvas

I am in the process of moving all images from our project into a `ResourceDictionary` to be used across all projects. When using Syncfusion Metro Studio I am able to get the XAML source of the images.

```
<Viewbox x:Shared="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Grid>
    <Grid Name="backgroundGrid" Width="48" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Path Data="M0,4.1309996L20.362437,4.1309996C20.038338,4.8125897,19.782439,5.5301299,19.594339,6.2769008L2.1451931,6.2769008 2.1451931,23.445208 30.042807,23.445208 30.042807,20.78887C30.342306,20.81167 30.642406,20.834471 30.949104,20.834471 31.367603,20.834471 31.781102,20.81027 32.188001,20.76737L32.188001,25.590239 20.922435,25.590239 20.922435,27.736771 23.605427,27.736771 23.605427,29.882 8.5839529,29.882 8.5839529,27.736771 11.265565,27.736771 11.265565,25.590239 0,25.590239z M29.967411,3.9921243L29.967411,8.1359167 25.823251,8.1359167 25.823251,10.100034 29.967411,10.100034 29.967411,14.243865 31.931586,14.243865 31.931586,10.100034 36.075645,10.100034 36.075645,8.1359167 31.931586,8.1359167 31.931586,3.9921243z M30.948448,0C35.985142,1.0841802E-08 40.067997,4.0825729 40.067997,9.1171007 40.067997,14.153367 35.985142,18.236 30.948448,18.236 25.912456,18.236 21.830998,14.153367 21.830998,9.1171007 21.830998,4.0825729 25.912456,1.0841802E-08 30.948448,0z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FF666666" Width="26" Height="26" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
          <TransformGroup.Children>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
          </TransformGroup.Children>
        </TransformGroup>
      </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
  </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The issue here is that I am creating buttons with the image next to my text as follows:

```
<corecontrols:IdyllicButton Name="btnClose" Height="30">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="/MHA.Modules.PolicyAdmin;component/Images/Cancel.png"/>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Text="Close"/>
    </StackPanel>
</corecontrols:IdyllicButton>
```

But I cannot set my `Image.ImageSource` to my `StaticResource` that I have created in a `ResourceDictionary` as I get the following error:

> An object of the type "System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox" cannot be
>   applied to a property that expects the type
>   "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource".

I have also tried using a canvas.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I think there is no need for <Image.../> You can add the Viewbox directly inside StackPanel

Comment: If you want to use it as image source, click on the Export button(Metro studio) it will ask format and file name save it as png.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this helps someone:

I found the solution, instead of using a `Image`, use the `Rectangle` control in its place and set the `OpacityMask` to the `Viewbox` resource.

```
<Rectangle Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Height="15"
        Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{StaticResource Close}"/>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

I found this scrolling `MahApps.Metro` source code for the `WindowCommand` Buttons.